# WP-Engine 502 timeout- what options do I have to get around this limitation?

Tags: wordpress

We have a plugin for Wordpress that we've been using successfully on many customers- the plugin syncs stock numbers with our warehouse and exports orders to our warehouse.

We have recently had a client move to WP-Engine who seem to impose a hard 30 second limit on the length of a running request. Because sometimes we have many orders to export, the script simply hits a 502 bad gateway error.

According to WP-Engine documentation, this cannot be turned off on a client by client basis.

https://wpengine.com/support/troubleshooting-502-error/

My question is, what options do I have to get around a host's 30 second timeout limit? Setting `set_time_limit` has no effect (as expected as it is the web server killing the request, not PHP). The only thing I can think of is make heavy modifications to the plugin whereby it acts as an API and we simply pull the data from the clients system, however this is a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

The long-process timeout is 60 seconds.
This cannot be turned off on shared plans, only plans with dedicated servers. You will not be able to get around this by attempting to modify it as it runs directly on Apache outside of your particular install

Your optons are:
1. 'Chunk' the upload to be smaller
2. Upload the sql file to your sFTP _wpeprivate folder and have their support import it for you.
3. Optimize the import so the content is imported more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three options here.

1. Change the web host (easy option).
2. Modify a plugin to process the sync in batches. However, this also won't give you a 100% guarantee with a hard script execution time limit - something may get lost in one or more batches and you won't even know.
3. Contact WP Engine and ask to raise the limit for this particular client.